# ¿Cómo generar números aleatorios de 100 a 150 dígitos? - C

Tags: c, random

Necesito generar números aleatorios de más de 100 dígitos para usarlos con el algoritmo de cifrado *RSA*. He buscado algoritmos para generarlos pero solo me permiten hasta 26 cifras, utilizando la librería ***ctime.h*** y para los números estoy usando `unsigned long long int` y los convierto a `mpz_t` de la libreria ***gmp.h*** para poder usarlos con *RSA*.

El código es el siguiente:

```
//Semilla de tiempo para generar los números aleatorios
void semilla(){
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    srand((time_t)ts.tv_sec);
}

//Genera números aleatorios de 16 cifras
unsigned long long int numeroAleatorio(){
    unsigned long long int numAleatorio = 0;
    numAleatorio = 1000000000000000
        + rand()%(10000000000000000
                 - 1000000000000000);
    return numAleatorio;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

soy nuevo en responder preguntas así que lo haré lo más correctamente posible. Una forma en la que podrías conseguir un número aleatorio con un tamaño comprendido entre 100 y 150 podría ser haciendo uso de un *array* de enteros. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <time.h>

int tamanoNumero();     /*Método para la generación del tamaño del número con dígitos entre 100 y 150*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int _longitud   =   tamanoNumero();     /*Variable con la longitud aleatoria del número*/

    printf("El tamaño del dígito es: %d \n",_longitud);

    int _numero[_longitud];     /*Array de tipo entero de tamaño _longitud*/

    for(int _digito = 0; _digito < _longitud; _digito++)    /*Bucle con "_longitud" iteraciones*/
        _numero[_digito]    = rand() % 10;      /*En cada celda del array, un número aleatorio entre 0 y 9*/



    printf("El número introducido es: ");

    for(int _d = 0; _d < _longitud; _d++)       /*Para mostrar el número generado total*/
        printf("%d",_numero[_d]);

    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}


int tamanoNumero(){

    srand(time(NULL));
    int _tamano = rand() % (150-100 +1) + 100;      /*Ofrece un número aleatorio entre 100 y 150*/

    return _tamano;
}
```

Notas: la idea está también en hacer uso de *srand()* que es lo que has usado en el tuyo para que la generación de números aleatorios sea diferente en cada ejecución del programa ya que con *rand()* parte de un número fijo y calcula los aleatorios a partir de ese número. La idea de por qué *rand()* tiene un tope de tamaño para la longitud de sus números tiene que ver por cuestiones de memoria aunque no lo sé con exactitud.

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: `srand()` debería llamarse en el `main`, no en `tamanoNumero`, ya que así garantizas la inicialización antes del primer uso (piensa en futuras refactorizaciones o ampliaciones). El límite de `rand` lo impone `RAND_MAX`, una constante cuyo valor depende del tipo `int`, que es el tipo de dato devuelto por `rand()`. Dado que es un tipo que ocupa típicamente 32 bits, el número más grande que puede generarse será (2^31 - 1), ya que un 1 bit lo ocupa el signo. Como ves, la memoria no tiene nada que ver en esto.

Comment: Hablé un poco desde la ignorancia en esa parte (mis disculpas) pero para futuras implementaciones lo tendré en cuenta. Por mi parte, muchas gracias.